# Issue with AJAX form submit success handler

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am experiencing an issue where my AJAX form post creates an alert that **seems to echo the entire page** rather than just the success message and I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. *Additionally I have followed numerous tips on stack to pass for data via serialize, but I am used to something such as `data { action: add, type: new }` and I am having issues attaching other variables to the post request onto data because of the `$(this).serialize();`*

PHP

```
if (isset($_POST['type']) && $_POST['type'] == 'email') {
    $emailFrom = EMAIL_FROM;
    $email_to = $_POST['email_to'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $body = $_POST['body'];
    if (mail($email_to, $subject, $body, "From: <$emailFrom>")) {
        return 'Email was successfully sent!';
    } else {
        return 'An error occured, email could not be sent.';
    }
    exit();
}
```

JS

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#user_email").submit(function(e) {
            var subject = $('#subject').val();
            var _body = $('#body').val();
            if (_body && subject) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: $(this).attr('action'),
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                       alert(data);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                alert ('Subject and Body fields are both required.');
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
    </script>
```

HTML

```
<h3>Send <?php echo $row_users['full_name'];?> an email</h3>
<div class="ec-messages messages-warning" style="width:300px;">Emails will be sent from the website default.</div>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" method="post" name="user_email" id="user_email">
<input name="email_to" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row_users['user_email'];?>">
<label>Subject</label><input type="text" name="subject" id="subject">
<label>Body</label><textarea name="body" id="body" rows="10" class="span5"></textarea>
<?php echo createFormButtons(true, true); ?>
</form>
```

Comment: instead of return just try echo ..

Comment: I don't see any input named 'type' in the html which your php is validating.

Comment: yea thats a variable i want to pass via ajax as sort of a switch to the php post but i dont know how (see italics)

Comment: You dont have any type field in your form. add that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
  if (isset($_POST['type']) && $_POST['type'] == 'email') {

  }
```

Well the above condition will find that if a field with name `type` and value 'email' is present or not

Since your ajax request is giving response as the whole HTML, this mean that this condition is not meet

JUST add the below line inside your form

```
   <input type='hidden' name='type' value='email' />
```

and let me know if this work out for you

Comment: Beat me to it by seconds. +1 for the right answer. haha

Comment: Either you or @bryan know what I'm talking about in the italics however? Aside from posting it the way you outlined as a hidden field, can I pass the type: email in the data hard-coded area of ajax before/with serialize?

Answer (score 3):

You are getting the entire page back because the first condition is not met.

```
if (isset($_POST['type']) && $_POST['type'] == 'email')
```

I don't see any input with the name `type` in your form, so instead of returning a result and `exit`ing it's just spitting back the entirety of the page. Try adding

```
<input type="hidden" name="type" value="email" />
```

To the form and see how that goes.

To add to the Op's inquiry jquery's `.serialize()` [returns a string](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) instead of adding the hidden input you may also try

```
 data: $(this).serialize() + '&type=email'
```

I've not tried this, but should work.